# ADD a column to SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to add a column to this query in SQL as below-

Comment: This is very unclear, what platform is this? Whats the connection between adding a column and a query & its results?  In general never store multiple values in a column, that's what rows are for.

Comment: Can you show us the rest of the query that is trying to "add a column in SQL"? Your question and code example aren't very clear. What flavor and version of SQL are you working in?

Comment: That query will not even run.  Google how to add column.

Answer (score 0):

You can try do this :

```
CUSIP=(Select TOP 1 gs.holdingsymbol 
           from dbo.holdingsymbol_tbl gs where gs.holdingsymboltypeid=2)
```

Comment: I dont want to restrict this. I want all results of this subquery, is it possible?

Comment: yes its possible, but.. i cant understand why you  don't put  this filter gs.holdingsymboltypeid = 2 into the where?

Answer (score 0):

you can use xml to store all result from query to a column

```
CUSIP=(Select gs.holdingsymbol 
           from dbo.holdingsymbol_tbl gs where gs.holdingsymboltypeid=2 for xml path(''))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery, you just need another condition on your `JOIN`, like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    h.tradingitemid
    ,h.securityid
    ,h.currencyId
    ,CUSIP = hs.holdingsymbol
FROM cpr..holding_tbl h
INNER JOIN cpr..HoldingSymbol_tbl hs ON h.holdingid = hs.holdingId AND hs.holdingsymboltypeid = 2
WHERE h.userCompanyId = 10;
```